# base64 preview for photos with html img on android firefox

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, base64

I am trying to make a preview of an image file before being uploaded. It works well on desktop/firefox but not on android/firefox (the picture is empty on android). Interesting behaviour: When the chosen file is relatively small it works, otherwise it does not(don't know the exact numbers, but 1.2MB pic is working with this code on android, whereas 3.5MB photo does not work). Here is the code for getting the base64 string for display reasons(newFile is the input type=file html element):

```
newFile.onchange = () => {
    if (newFile.files && newFile.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {

            //other stuff...

            let doc = {
                id: -1,
                creator: userBean.kennzeichen,
                creationDate: dateString,
                base64image: e.target.result    //here I store the image
            };
            let docDiv = renderDocDiv(doc);     //and pass the doc object for rendering out all the details
            newFile.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', docDiv);
            log('onload done');
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(newFile.files[0]);
        log('after readURL');
    }
};
```

all the log output is coming through, the image element is created but the pic remains empty on android. In renderDocDiv I do something along those lines:

```
//other stuff...

let pic = document.createElement('img');
pic.src = doc.base64image;
container.appendChild(pic);
return container;
```

It is no worky and I have no clue why...
Any hints are highly appreciated ;)

Comment: simplified the question ;)

Comment: Everything but the logic of `resizedataURL` makes sense. What's the final output of `resizedataURL`?

Comment: As mentioned above, the resizedataURL was a stupid idea as it uses the same method (.src = dataURL). The 'output' was a small version of the image as base64 encoded string set to the given img element(=pic). The reduction works on its own, but did not reduce the size for obvious reasons.
As mentioned in the post, I've also tried to set the dataurl direct as .src which also did not work(without all the resize shenanigans). After some testing I think everything above 1.6MB does not work anymore...?

Comment: Right, but I'm not not seeing the updated code for it. Everything is pointing toward that function as the problem. What happens if you stop resizing it or manually create the img tag with `<img src="{base64}">`?

Comment: edited the original post once more. Removed the resize function and did further compression on the example.